# Правильное подключение к БД

Tags: java, sql, многопоточность, postgresql

Задача вот в чем -- нужно вставить в таблицу (например) 10000 строк. Через ExecutorService сделал чтобы каждая строка вставлялась в отдельном потоке.

Вопрос: как правильно подключатся к БД postgresql, для каждого query свой коннект или один на всех. Если один на всех не будут ли они конфликтовать там (одновременно вставляя данные)? Слышал что база данных с многопоточностью не очень хорошо дружат..

Comment: Не очень знаком с используемыми вами вещами, но вставлять 10000 записей в базу, да каждую в отдельном потоке - так точно нельзя делать.

Comment: "Вставлять каждую строчку из 10к в одельном потоке" с разгромным счётом проиграет вставке 10к строк одним `INSERT`'ом в одном соединении.

Comment: если есть несколько активных параллельных запросов то лучше иметь пулл коннектов к базе данных (наиболее производительный это Hikari), и вставлять не по 1-ой строке, а батчами.

Answer (score 0):

Тут многопоточность не нужна. Просто разбейте на пачки по 5000 - 10000 записей и вставляйте одним подготовленным запросом. Как-то так:

```java
connection.setAutoCommit(false);  
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO tab (id, name, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");            
for (Record record : records) {
    ps.setInt(1, record.id);
    ps.setString(2, record.name);
    ps.setInt(3, record.value);
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```